# JNI: transfer a multiple-dimension java array to c program

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

In Java, a multiple-dimension array of non-primitive objects, e.g. `Integer[][] arr`, is defined. How should one access the array `arr` in a C program via JNI?

```
public class Foo {
    public static Integer[][] arr = {{0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};
}
```

Comment: `int a[][3] = {{0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};` Give it a try!!

Comment: Not translate: By JNI, I need to access the java data from a c program.

Answer (score 8):

First, get the field ID:

```
jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "fully/qualified/package/Foo");
jfieldID field = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, clazz, "arr", "[[Ljava/lang/Integer;" );
```

Then  you'll need to use this to get the actual field. Supposing you have a `jobject` of type `Foo` called `fooObj`:

```
jobject arrObj = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, fooObj, field);
```

`arr` can be cast into a `jObjectArray`, and you can manipulate the array using the jni array functions. Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17314).

Since you have a 2D array of Integer objects, you will have to go through the usual means to get the primitive type from the Integer class.

Comment: Thank you, krsteeve. Now, I can get the size of each row, but I encountered problem when casting jobject to jint, for example, 2 => 22164352.

Comment: You have a 2D array of `Integer` objects, they are not `int`'s, and you can't just cast them to `jint`. You'll have to either change your array to the primitive type, or go through the usual means to get the primitive type from the `Integer` class

Answer (score 1):

At present, it is impossible to directly transfer a multiple-dimension array of some non-primitive objects from a Java program to a C program.

A solution to this problem is to make a primitive version of the non-primitive multiple-dimension array, and to transfer the primitive multiple-dimension array from Java to C. Anyway, such a multiple-dimension array is transferred as a `jobjectArray` natively.

The outline of working on a 2-dimension array of integer numbers is as follows:

1. make a primitive version of the non-primitive multiple-dimension array in Java;
2. get the array as `jobjectArray` in native C program;
3. use `GetObjectArrayElement` to iterate each *row*;
4. use `GetIntArrayElements` function to iterate each *cell*, e.g. `jint *val = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, row, NULL);`.

Comment: You say it's impossible, but then you proceed to demonstrate how to do it. I'm not following you. Do you mean it's impossible to cast a Java multidimensional array into a contiguous block of array elements in C? Yes, that's impossible.

Comment: I mean `directly transferring' is impossible :-)

Comment: Is *is* possible, they'll just be jobjects... then you'll have to get the int values from the `Integer` class as you would in Java, using jni